# Why can't this triangulate $\mathbb{RP}^2$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, triangulation, simplicial-complex

I understand that an actual minimal triangulation of $\mathbb{RP}^2$ has at least 10 2-simplices, but I don't understand why.

Without appealing to the computation of the homology groups of $\mathbb{RP}^2$, why can't the following picture be a triangulation of $\mathbb{RP}^2$? What goes wrong?

[image]

Comment: It looks like there are two edges from $0$ to $1$. That isn't allowed in a triangulation.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan - Ah hah! I see now! Thank you!

Comment: @Rachel: $\mathbb{R}{\mathbb{P}^2}$ is like $S^2$ that contains a Moebius-Strip, it's not orientable. That's another reason.

Comment: @Frieder - Hmm, I don't understand what you mean by this. $\mathbb{RP}^2$ is triangulable, but not with the (faulty) triangulation I've given. What does non-orientability have to do with it?

Comment: @Rachel: From the view of differentiable manifolds, $\mathbb{R}{P^2}$ is like the famous Klein-Bottle (Kleinsche Flasche). A non-orientable submanifold embedded in ${\mathbb{R}^4}$
without self-intersection. So I'm not sure in this case, if non-orientability and triangulization contradict each other or not.
Would be lucky about, you can tell it to me.

Comment: Every smooth manifold (such as $\mathbb{R}P^2$) is triangulable, even though many of them are nonorientable. Orientability doesn't have anything to do with being triangulable (as far as I know).

Answer (score 1):

Each 2 simplex must be determined uniquely by its vertices. The two 0-1-2 simplexes
have the same vertices.

The edges here are OK because they are identified in the projective plane.

- Orientability has nothing to do with it.  The thing about an unorientable n-manifold without boundary is it can not be triangulated so that any integer combination of the n simplices forms a cycle. But it can still be triangulated.

Comment: You think all four edges in this diagram from $0$ to $1$ are intended to be identified? I don't think the result will be a manifold.